# Storing array data in foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am wondering how can I store all values from a foreach loop, I know that I am re-initialising in the loop but I'm not sure how to store the data. Heres my basic loop:

```
$array = array("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4");
foreach($array as $row){
    $arr = array('val' => $row);
    echo $row;
}
print_r($arr);
```

So when I use the `print_r($arr)` the only thing outputted would be `v4` and I know that the values are there because the `echo $row;` does return each output individually.

My question would be how can I store each instance of row in my array?

Comment: `$arr[] = array('val' => $row);` perhaps? But what do you actually want $arr to be after the loop?

Comment: read an array and creating same array. right? or you want two dimentional array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new array, fill it:

```
$array = array("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4");

$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $row){
    // notice the brackets
    $newArray[] = array('val' => $row);

}

print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: This sorts the issue, thanks also can I ask by creating a multi-dimensional array how can I get the `$array`? As right now this is what I get `Array ( [0] => Array ( [val] => v1 ) [1] => Array ( [val] => v2 ) [2] => Array ( [val] => v3 ) [3] => Array ( [val] => v4 ) )` And I am wondering how can I get the values in `Array`?

Comment: @user3144542 please report a concrete use case [i.e. some real and thus non dummy data].

Comment: Well the values should be the same but in the end I would like to use the keys as a column name in an SQL statement and the values as the value I am searching for. To do this I will use CI built in method which searches with associative arrays heres a [link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select). Thats why I want to get the values like this `'val' => v1 'val' => v2, 'val' => v2`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are storing your array wrong.

Try adjusting the $arr = array('val' => $row);

to:

$arr[] = array('val' => $row);

This will set it so you pick up each line as a separate array which you can easily navigate through.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading correctly, you want to transform your array from simple values to key-value pairs of 'val'->number.  array_map is a concise way of doing this sort of transformation.

```
$array = array("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4");
$arr = array_map(function($v) { return array('val'=>$v); }, $array);
print_r($arr);
```

While it doesn't matter in this case, array_map also has the handy feature of preserving your keys, in case that is desired.

Note that you can also provide a named function to array_map, instead of providing the implementation inline, which can be nice in the event that your transform method gets more complicated. More on array_map [here](http://www.php.net/array_map).